# How to add spaces(new lines) at the end of a file until it is of a certain size?(In Java)

Tags: java

I want to add spaces(or new lines) to a file until the file size in bytes % 512 == 0, please help me (in Java).

I tried

```
while(my_file.length()%512!=0)
{ 
writer.write("\n");
}
```

, 
but it gives me an infinite loop, bypasses the condition % 512(I added a System.out.println in the while to see the size and it just keeps increasing), and besides is a "\n" 1 byte length? for it doesn't seem like it from the output I get

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: do you get the same behavior with spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't tried anything, I'll give you some pseudo code to start you off.

```
while ((file.length() % 512) != 0) {
    writeNewLineToFile("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29
gives you the length (size) of the file object in bytes

Answer (score 0):

Do a check on

```
 file.length()
```

and add text to your file till your required file size is reached .